# break in refreshing my custom combo box column in RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, combobox, telerik

I have created a custom grid column for a `RadGridview` which based on the row `DataItem` which is a class, finds the corresponding items and put them in the `Combobox`.

When the page loads, the custom column is freeing to be created only for the rows that are in visual and for other rows, it has been fired to be created when the user scrolls down. Unfortunately, when the user scroll the wrong combo boxes are created for each row.

For example, run the below sample and see the combobox in front of dimensionless row, which must be empty which is correct. Now scroll down and click on a cell and scroll up to the dimension row, which now have a `Combobox` with values which is erroneous. Note that the dimensions combo box is shifted up now!

Why the combo boxes are wrong after scrolling or windows size change?

Comment: any one does not have any idea on the uploaded sample?

Comment: I have edit your post. And Removed the Stample. For Many reason: 1/. If it's not in your question So dont get anything from it.  2/. It's a Rar.

Comment: A code repository, ok I get it. But a Rar seriously ?! It's a great thing that your question include a [mcve] but is it really a MCVE ? or it's a low-quality, fix-my-code-for-you type of questions?

Comment: @PierreLebon - Hi. actually i need the code ecause i need a very large no of Enums to e created to e more than a view in grid to reproduce the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Virtualization which is causing the behaviour you describe.

You can disable this on a RadGridView like so:

```
EnableRowVirtualization="False"
```

This will cause all your data to load whether it's in view or not, and if you have a lot of data this can cause significant performance issues.